# How to insert 200 photos to HTML <img> tags by not adding one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

I have a situation that there is gallery with a few categories, and each have like 200 photos. What is best optional and simple way to handle that not adding one by one in HTML?

The website is based on HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, not WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript you can create HTML elements:

```
imgArr = // I am not sure if you're reading them from a file, etc. But we need an array of all the images src location
body = document.getElementById('imagelocation') // Where you want the img tags to be
for (let i = 0;i<imgArr.length;i++) {
  newImg = document.createElement('IMG')
  newImg.src = imgArr[i].url // Adds the src for the where the image is located
  newImg.classList.add('styling') // Optional. We can add styling to the images, i.e., make them all of a uniform size
  body.appendChild(newImg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solutions

Here are a few quick and easy-to-read ways of doing something like this:

**Make sure to read the performance section at the bottom**

### Using a `forEach()` loop

```js
// Images array holds the URLs/directories of the images
const urls = [
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503803548695-c2a7b4a5b875',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500382017468-9049fed747ef'
]

// Get the element by id
const imagesSection = document.querySelector('#images')

// Loop all URLs
urls.forEach(url => {
  // Insert the elements into the image section
  images.innerHTML += `<img src="${url}" height="100">`
})
```

```html
<!-- images container -->
<div id="images">

</div>
```

---

### Using a `for(... of ...)` loop

```js
// Images array holds the URLs/directories of the images
const urls = [
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503803548695-c2a7b4a5b875',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500382017468-9049fed747ef'
]

// Get the element by id
const imagesSection = document.querySelector('#images')

// Loop through all URLs
for (url of urls) {
  // Add images to imges section
  imagesSection.innerHTML += `<img src="${url}" height="100" >`
}
```

```html
<!-- images container -->
<div id="images">

</div>
```

---

### Using a `for()` loop

```js
// Images array holds the URLs/directories of the images
const urls = [
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503803548695-c2a7b4a5b875',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500382017468-9049fed747ef'
]

// Get the element by id
const imagesSection = document.querySelector('#images')

// Loop through all URLs
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  // Get the current URL
  const url = urls[i]
  // Add images to the images section
  imagesSection.innerHTML += `<img src="${url}" height="100" >`
}
```

```html
<!-- images container -->
<div id="images">

</div>
```

---

## Performance

Being that you are going to be adding many elements to the DOM you should not use `innerHTML` as I did in my code examples (I used it for readability and cleaner code). `innerHTML` will reparse and recreate all of the DOM elements in the `div` element. Instead, you would do something like this to create the `img` elements.

```js
const urls = [
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503803548695-c2a7b4a5b875',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500382017468-9049fed747ef'
]

// Get the element by id
const imagesSection = document.querySelector('#images')

// Loop through all URLs
urls.forEach(url => {
  // Create image node
  const img = document.createElement('img')

  // Make src equal to the URL
  img.setAttribute('src', url)
  img.setAttribute('height', '100') // Ignore me (just makes images smaller)

  // Append img node to image section
  imagesSection.appendChild(img)
})
```

```html
<div id="images">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the fun since many answers are efficient.

Here is a loop of 200 looking at pictures from picsum and dispatching them in a grid:

```js
galery = document.querySelector('#galery')
for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  img = document.createElement('IMG')
  img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/' + i * 4 + '/200/100'
  img.setAttribute('alt', img.src)
  img.classList.add('img')
  galery.appendChild(img)
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
  border: solid;
  transition: 0.15s
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 4% 5px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.img:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="galery"></div>
```

Comment: I have images at src = 'images/' how to handle that? now changed your code to mine src photos are not showing

Comment: I handled that this way: img.src = 'images/id/' + i + '.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by naming all the images in your folder to img0.png,img1.png....img199.png(you can use a simple python code to rename your image) and then use the javascript code below to add them to the DOM by looping through them

```
<div><p id="photos" /></div>


<script>
var container=
document.getElementById("photos");
for (var i=0, len<200,i++) {
 var img = new Image();
 var imgname=“img”+i+”.png”;
 img.src = imgname;
 container.appendChild(img);}
</script>
```